# How much alcohol has changed hands as part of the "Whisky War"?

Tags: international-relations, armed-conflict, canada, borders, denmark

Canada and Denmark have a territorial dispute over [Hans Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Island) between Ellesmere Island and Greenland in the arctic.  [Starting in 1984](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/08/world/what-in-the-world/canada-denmark-hans-island-whisky-schnapps.html), each country has sent expeditions which have placed their own national welcome notes, put up their own flag, and left accompanying bottles of alcohol as tokens of hospitality, (Denmark leaves Schnapps and Canada leaves Rye Whisky).  Some people have dubbed this the ["Whisky War"](http://www.businessinsider.fr/us/canada-and-denmark-whiskey-war-over-hans-island-2016-1/).

All the articles I've come across suggest that has cycled several times with each country replacing the other country's sign, flag, and alcohol with their own but I haven't seen any indication of how often this happens.  So does anyone know how much booze has changed hands over the course of the "war"?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't known as the visits are not scheduled to a set timetable. From [CBC](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/north/canada-denmark-should-turn-hans-island-into-a-condominium-academics-1.3315640):

> The militaries of both countries periodically visit to remove the other guy's flag and leave a bottle of Danish schnapps or Canadian whisky.
>
> Under the terms of a 2005 agreement, both countries have agreed to inform the other before they visit.

Comment: That means it's not predictable.  I'm asking if there's any publicly available information about how many times it *has* happened.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened every year, then it would be 33 bottles.

Given the average whiskey bottle is 750ML, the amount of alcohol would be approximately 24.750 liters.

Comment: 24.75 liters? Also, if you could show that it actually happens once a year, it would be an appropriate answer, but currently it is just a guess.

Comment: Corrected the value, missed the dot when typing,thanks. I made sure this was "if" as there are no accurate records as to the frequency at which this event occurred.

Comment: Are there no accurate records, or do you just assume there are no accurate records? I might sound nit-picking, but this is a Question&Answer site where people expect they get an answer only if someone knows the answer. We can all guess more or less precisely, but saying "I don't know, maybe once a year, maybe not" is not an accurate answer. You are new here, so please feel invited to take a tour on the site to see what it is and what it is not: https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: In Denmark (and Greenland, I suppose), a bottle of snaps will usually be 700 mL, not 750 mL. This is unlike ordinary wine which is usually 750 (like in France).